# How can I limit access to Azure Function App Proxy URLs?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I have an Azure Function App Proxy set up with OAuth2 (Google) authentication, that proxies requests to a blob storage account. My idea was to use the proxy as an authentication/authorization layer to a static HTML site stored in the blob storage.

OK, so the authentication works, but now anyone with a Google account can see the content. How can I control the access, say limit to a configurable set of accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't find a quick way to do it with function app proxy, and API management seemed to just complicate things (authorization server? how many servers do I need for a small team static site with some automatically-published stats on what we do?), so I opted for a proxy function app, and here it is:

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{

    var authURI = new Uri(req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
    var path = authURI.MakeRelativeUri(req.RequestUri);
    var prefix = "api/myfunction";
    var fileName = path.ToString().Remove(0,prefix.Length);

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Authorization - allow only @myorg.com users
    IEnumerable<string> headerValues = req.Headers.GetValues("X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME");
    var user = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
    if (!user.EndsWith("@myorg.com", true, null))
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Unauthorized");
    }

    var blobStorageURI = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager              
         .ConnectionStrings["BLOB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT"].ConnectionString;
    var container = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
         .ConnectionStrings["BLOB_CONTAINER"].ConnectionString;
    var authKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
         .ConnectionStrings["BLOB_ACCESS_STRING"].ConnectionString;
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(blobStorageURI);
        var storagePath = "/" + container + fileName + authKey;
        return await client.GetAsync(storagePath);
    }
}
```

Here's the function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "myfunction/{*path}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "head"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

- Note the routing and the relation between the routing and the hard-coded "myfunction".
- It's also possible to get rid of the "api" prefix using the host.json file.
- Also note the connection strings that define the access to the blob storage. I created a SAS (Shared Access Signature) for that.